# Move from content to simple-fields

Tags: php, wordpress, scripting

I'm trying to move text from content to fields in the plugin "simple-fields" on wordpress. it is text like "Author: John Doe" "Source: stackorverflow.com" and the likes of these. What is after : usually differs, post to post. but in the simple-fields I got most of the needed fields. So I want to move automatically author to author, source to source, date to date etc, easy.

I have used the plugin "search-regex" for wordpress before, it is awesome. I tried to rewrite this plugin but this was to advanced for me, as I dont know much scripting. I really hope you may be able to help me, thanks.

Comment: It's helpful to add specific bits of code related to your problem so we can more easily identify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so we have the code from the content, that can look something like this:

```
      `<p class="ref">published 
      <!-- #BeginDate format:Ge1 -->01.01.1999<!-- #EndDate -->
    <br/>
    Speaker: Dr. Speaker<br/>
    Lecture:  Lecture about choclate<br/>
Source: <a href="http://choclateman.choclate">http://choclateman.choclate</a>`
```

Now I have a row in simplefields for the date, one for speaker, author (depending on if it is a lecture or a book), a row for source and some extra rows for things like lecture etc.

Anyhow how I can move all these to simplefield values, so every post that has these rows or similar in the begin of its content, have them moved from content to simplefields?

if anything is missing, please be like this person that is trying to help, and tell me about it. I really many people here can help, but I don't really understand how you want me to formulate the question for you people to consider helping, so again, please, tell if something is missing...